# WPF C# How do you return a list of all columns in a LinqtoSql dbml object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

What I'm trying to do is return all column names in a LinqtoSql dbml table object in any form that can be turned into a List object and be displayed to the user.

The reason for this is I have a DxGrid with a hard coded Xaml column definition that only displays a subset of the dbml table columns.

I want to allow the user to select from the other columns that are not currently visible and from there I can create new column objects and add the selected columns to the collection in the grid.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In my humble opinion, it appears that you are expecting too much by asking that question. Please read the [How do I ask a good question]() help page to learn how to ask better, more focused questions here, which will lead to you getting better and quicker answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As each table column is represented by a property in your Linq2Sql class, getting their names can be done quite easily through reflection. In the `Type` of the Linq2Sql class, simply search for properties that are decorated with Linq's `ColumnAttribute`.

Here's an example for a database table "Building":

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
...
...

var columnNames = typeof(Building)
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false).Any())
                    .Select(p => p.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're still dealing with a concrete object type at then end of the day, like the Product class from the Northwind database, you could enumerate the public properties of the return type using reflection and create your list that way.

```
var columnNames = typeof(Product).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
```

From there you can compare the complete list to your hard-coded set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does get the list but I had to mark Sphinxxx as the correct one because their solution also removes the dbml table associations from the returned list in the query.